# Android Actionbar icons appearing to be blurred

Tags: android-actionbar, android-drawable, blur, android-menu, android-screen-support

My Actionbar icons are appearing to be blurred in the emulator as well as ma phone.

1. I have tried to increase the dimensions of the icons,the size of icons is increasing but its again showing the same blurred icons.
2. I have also tried to add the  in manifest still thr is no effect.
3. I also tried to change my min sdk to 14 but still thr is no change in the icons.

Please help i am stucked in this from last one month..

### MainActivity

```
          @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        openBottomSheet();

        return true;


    }

    else if(id==R.id.action_stories_settings){


        Settings();


    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.appsfreax.humansofindia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.appsfreax.humansofindia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name=".app.ParseApplication"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/humans_india_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
       >






    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Submit_story"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sumit_story" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.All_stories"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Errorview"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: If you change the package name of this sample app,
              change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" in the lines
              below to match the new package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.appsfreax.humansofindia" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>
```

### Build.gradle

```
                apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

       android {
          compileSdkVersion 23
             buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appsfreax.humansofindia"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 102
    versionName "1.0.2"
}
```

### Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/t"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Botttom menu"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />



<item
    android:id="@+id/action_stories_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

### Blurred Image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2xbmgzcrhmcHk2QnR4V3lsWWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you find a solution? It looks like I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems problem with the icon size you're using. I believe you're using small icon which is being stretched and looks blurry.

Try using atleast 70px*70px png canvas with 48x48 icon inside (IMO). Refer the image below.

if you want bigger/lesser icon size you can change the icon size accordingly.

[image]

hope this helps :)

Comment: Instead you can generate icons from 'Romanurik Asset Studio' google it, to generate icons for all the apps, It generates the 5 icons set for you, and yeah you'll never have the blur issue in Action bar.